# Kotlin JSON parsing to response object with Retrofit?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

The JSON I should serialize automatically by Retrofit (GsonConverterFactory):

```
{
   "id":1,
   "result":{
      "list":[
         {
            "user":{
               "firstName":"John",
               "lastName":"Smith"
            },
            "id":45,
            "changes":{
               "firstName":{
                  "old":"John",
                  "new":"Jane"
               },
               "lastName":{
                  "old":"Smith",
                  "new":"Liam"
               },
               "emails":[
                  {
                     "old":"email@email.com",
                     "new":"mail@mail.org"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My Retrofit API:

```
 fun getData(@Header("Access-Token") token: String): Call<GetDataResponse>
```

My question: How should my `GetDataResponse` data class (and the included data classes) look like for auto serializing?

The `Changes` can contain a lot more different attribute like *firstName*, etc. (but I know them all).
I need to show the changes dinamically in a list -  nothing more. But with this json structure I can't serialize.
I tried Json to Kotlin converter and klaxon, but it fails of course, it can't serialize automatically because of the structure of the json...

Comment: To me, https://json2kt.com/ seems to do the job. BR

Comment: Not a good solution, I shoul hardcode the "firstName", "emails", etc... If there is a new type, I have to create a new build... It's not dynamic... (And the auto parse not working with this)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Then an approach with `changes` of type Map<String, Any> should be the tested.  BR